# Why "php artisan queue:listen or queue:work" doesn't work in IIS 2012?

Tags: laravel, iis, queue

I have been having trouble using the laravel queue since it won't work when I use it on the Windows Server, but when I use it locally on my laptop it works fine, do you guys know any work around for this to work?

Comment: The [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker) suggest using supervisor to manage the queue worker. This [does work in windows](https://pypi.org/project/supervisor-win/) but requires python to be installed.  There are probably [alternatives](https://github.com/ochinchina/supervisord) and [further discussions](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-way-to-use-queues-on-a-windows-server) for anyone who puts in the effort to search for them as well

Comment: I found a document about it, is this the right one? http://supervisord.org/installing.html ?

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment the link for windows supervisor is [here](https://pypi.org/project/supervisor-win/). The link you found only works under linux

Comment: @apokryfos thank you, it seems that there are no tutorials on how to use supervisor for windows.

Comment: Once you install it as a windows service it works identically as in linux so everything in http://supervisord.org/configuration.html should apply to windows as well

Comment: @apokryfos I actually get this error 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwd'`